# Allow users to add modules to a page using react components

Tags: reactjs, components, builder

I am trying to build a tool that would essentially work as a "web page builder" where a user can click to add a module, select from a list of options and then have those modules injected/added/appended to the page in a specific order.

Paperbits(https://demo.paperbits.io/) is the best example of what I am trying to accomplish. when the user selects a module it is added where the selected the plus button and can be edited from there.

I am using react.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign an ID to each module. When you select a module(component), you can push that ID to an array. You can then use that array to map and render the module based on the ID.